# Why does MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser use a dispatch queue internally?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, nsnetservice, multipeer-connectivity

While I was browsing through the iOS 7 runtime headers, something caught my eye. In the [MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser class](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/MultipeerConnectivity.framework/MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser.h), part of the Multipeer Connectivity framework, a property called `syncQueue` is and multiple methods prefixed with `sync` are defined. Some of the methods both exist in a prefixed and non-prefixed version, such as `startAdvertisingPeer` and `syncStartAdvertisingPeer`.

My question is, what would be the purpose of both this property and these prefixed methods, and how are they combined?

(edit: removed the remark that the queue is serial as pointed out by CouchDeveloper, since we cannot know this)

Answer (score 1):

As you know, the implementation is private.

Having a dispatch queue whose name is `syncQueue` may not mean that this queue is a serial queue. It might be a concurrent queue as well.

We can only have a guess what the `startAdvertisingPeer` and the "prefixed" version `syncStartAdvertisingPeer` might mean.

For example, in order to fulfill internal prerequisites `startAdvertisingPeer` *might* assume that it is always invoked from an execution context *except* the *syncQueue*.  That way, it can *synchronously* dispatch to the syncQueue with invoking `syncStartAdvertisingPeer` without ending up in a deadlock. On the other hand, `syncStartAdvertisingPeer` will always assume to execute on the *syncQueue*, that way guaranteeing concurrency.

But, as stated, we don't know the actual details - it's just a rough guess. Usually, you should read the documentation - and not some private header details to draw a picture in your mind how this class might likely work.